# what does the ${_2F_1}\left[\cdot, \cdot, \cdot, \cdot\right]$ function mean?

Tags: notation, special-functions

I was reading the [integral tables](http://integral-table.com/downloads/integral-table.pdf), where it says:

\begin{equation}
\int \cos^p ax dx  = -\frac{1}{a(1+p)}{\cos^{1+p} ax} \times
{_2F_1}\left[
\frac{1+p}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3+p}{2}, \cos^2 ax
\right]
\end{equation}

May I ask what does the ${_2F_1}\left[\cdot, \cdot, \cdot, \cdot\right]$ function mean?

Comment: You may ask--and we may inquire where you searched before asking...

Comment: @Did my bad. I searched "function F" and missed the point. Now i get it -- i can simply search "2F1".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is [hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function). We usually write it as $_2F_1[a,b;c;z]$, not $_2F_1[a,b,c,z]$.

For $|z|\lt 1$, the hypergeometric function is defined as
$$_2F_1[a,b;c;z]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a)_n(b)_n}{(c)_n}\cdot\frac{z^n}{n!}$$
where 
$$(q)_n=\begin{cases}q(q+1)\cdots (q+n-1)&\text{if}\ n\gt 0\\1&\text{if}\ n=0\end{cases}$$
Here, $(q)_n$ is called as [Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol).

Comment: This is because there can be dynamic arguments. The first subtext before the F means two of the first group of parameters. The second  subtext after the F is the number of parameters in the second group. Finally the z is the main argument.

Comment: @Ali, traditionally they are termed as "numerator parameters" and "denominator parameters", corresponding to their positions in the defining Maclaurin series.